# can not delete the entity using session.delete()

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, associations

I have some entity in my application,and some of them are many-to-many association,when I try to delete them I get the error:"Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint....".

This is the example:

```
class Task{
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="task")
  List<TaskStep> steps;
}
class TaskStep{
  @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  Task task;
  @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALl)
  List<Operator> operators
}
class Operator{
  @ManyToMany(mappedBy=opertors)
  List<TaskStep> steps;
}
```

When I want to delete a task object,I will get the exception.

Why? I just want to delete the task object itself, and the related rows in the t_taskstep_t_operator.

How to make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
class Task{
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  List<TaskStep> steps;
}
```

It will delete the corresponding entry from TaskStep as well.

Comment: Do you mean that set the cascade in the two sides?